# integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor & Warning: Reached the maximum number of function evaluations (10000)

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I am trying to do a set of integrations for a particular value of psi and theta. These integrations are then combined into a formula to give P. The idea is then to do this for a set of psi and theta from 0 to pi/2 and then plot the results of P against a function of theta and psi.

I get two errors, firstly 
integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor
not sure how to change the integral to make it the right dimensions to psi no longer being a scalar.

I also get Warning: Reached the maximum number of function evaluations (10000) for i3, is this a serious error, (as in has the integration not been computed) I tried changing the type of integration or changing the error tolerance and this seemed to have no effect on removing the actual error..

```
eta = input('Enter Dielectric Constant 1.5-4:  ');
sdev = input('Enter STD DEV (roughness) maybe 0.1:  ');

psi = [0:0.01:pi/2];
theta = [0:0.01:pi/2];
r = sqrt((sin(psi)).^2+(sin(theta).*(cos(psi))).^2);

calpha = (cos(theta+dtheta)).*(cos(psi+dpsi));
rp01 = calpha-sqrt(eta-1+((calpha).^2));
rp02 = calpha+sqrt(eta-1+((calpha).^2));
rperp = (rp01./rp02).^2;
rp11 = ((eta.*calpha)-sqrt(eta-1+((calpha).^2)));
rp12 = ((eta.*calpha)+sqrt(eta-1+((calpha).^2)));
rpar = (rp11./rp12).^2;

qthingy1 = ((sin(psi+dpsi)).^2)-((sin(theta+dtheta)).^2).*((cos(psi+dpsi)).^2);
qthingy2 = ((sin(psi+dpsi)).^2)+((sin(theta+dtheta)).^2).*((cos(psi+dpsi)).^2);
qthingy = qthingy1./qthingy2;

wthingy1 = (sin(2*(psi+dpsi))).*(sin(theta+dtheta));
wthingy2 = ((sin(psi+dpsi)).^2)+(sin((theta+dtheta)).^2).*((sin(psi+dpsi)).^2);
wthingy = wthingy1./wthingy2;

roughness = (cos(psi)./(2*pi*(sdev.^2))).*exp(-((cos(psi).*dtheta).^2+(dpsi).^2)/(2*sdev.^2));

fun = matlabFunction((rpar+rperp).*roughness,'vars',{dtheta,dpsi});
fun2 = matlabFunction(roughness,'vars',{dtheta,dpsi});
fun3 = matlabFunction((rpar+rperp).*roughness.*qthingy,'vars',{dtheta,dpsi});
fun4 = matlabFunction((rpar+rperp).*roughness.*wthingy,'vars',{dtheta,dpsi});
thetamax = (pi/2) - theta;
psimax = (pi/2) - psi;

A = integral2(fun2,-pi/2,pi/2,-pi/2,pi/2);
i1 = (integral2(fun,-pi/2,thetamax,-pi/2,psimax))./A;

q = 2 - i1;
i2 = (integral2(fun3,-pi/2,thetamax,-pi/2,psimax))./A;
i3 = (integral2(fun4,-pi/2,thetamax,-pi/2,psimax))./A;

P = sqrt(i2.^2+i3.^2)./i1
plot(P, r);
```

Comment: I suggested using *either* `syms` and `matlabFunction` *OR* doing it numerically. This mixture using numerical input and `matlabFunction` won't work! Are you missing `syms dtheta dpsi`?

Comment: Something is wrong with your formulas. Your functions `fun`,`fun2`,... should evaluate to a single value, but return a vector. I suspect you should remove all occurences of your variable `theta` and `psi`.

Comment: Apologies, I wanted to post in the old thread but it seemed against overstack policy. I'm confused how would I use syms to parameterise my psi and theta? and where do I need the syms dtheta dpsi? It seemed to do the integral without (when I just had psi and theta as an input)

Comment: Also it would make sense that the functions would be a vector, because you have all the different potential inputs for theta and psi?

Comment: But not for a single input!

Comment: Do you have the mathematical formula of the function you are trying to integrate?

Comment: You see what I'm trying to get at though? yes its in the code. You mean do I have it analytically?

Comment: I see where the problem is, but I'm unsure how to clarify. Your usage of both `psi` and `dpsi` as well as `dtheta` and `theta` at the same time is the thing. In your math-formula you wouldn't have both of those. In the previous question I didn't see this problem as there were so many different variables. That's why I would like to see the formula to give you a clean solution.

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img540/1903/4D1diY.jpg but cos(alpha)=cos(theta)cos(psi) so this changes to cos(alpha)=cos(theta+dtheta)*(cos(psi+dpsi))

Comment: I mean It doesn't seem that crazy (in my head) we want to integrate over dthetha and dpsi and we want to make theta and psi vary in such a way that we get a different integral value (recorded) for each shift along that so we can plot P.

Comment: Hm, ok. So it's true you should keep both variables. I suspect the problem is still: Your `theta` and `psi` should be single values for each call of `integral2`, so best solution is to use two loops for `theta` and `psi`.

Comment: So you want to do a surface plot for varying values of `theta` and `psi`?

Comment: `fun4` is the problem, when plotted you can see that the only nonzero values are on a line...

Comment: According to my supervisor there is some degeneracy between the theta and psi values (I haven't learnt all the spherical astronomy) So I shouldn't need a 3D plot, only 2D using r as defined in the code. I made an error in the function that goes into fun4, it should be     wthingy2 = ((sin(psi+dpsi)).^2)+(sin((theta+dtheta)).^2).*((cos(psi+dpsi)).^2); how do I go about these two loops?

Comment: `wthingy2` has `sin` instead of `cos`. You will also need loops for `psi` and `theta`.

Comment: so essentially my loop will create a set of points for each value of theta and psi that i put in, treating them as scalars and then at the end I plot all those points in a graph? Can't we just keep the vector formulation of the problem